# Deciding the language of Page Speed Insights

Tags: performance, configuration, settings, pagespeed-insights, google-pagespeed-insights-api

I'll appreciate if someone can tell me how to get the page speed insights from Google in English. They weirdly appear to me in Spanish while I have nothing set up in Spanish. I use either Catalan or English and in this case I would need the English wording.

I've tried but can't find where to change the language. Don't know how to avoid it appearing in Spanish.

Thantks in advance!

Kind regards,
Nuria

Answer (score 0):

PageSpeed Insights uses the `Accept-Language:` HTTP header to determine the language that is displayed.

In Chrome this is set in `chrome://settings/languages` (or Settings -> Languages).